# Cron running rake task "could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources"

Tags: cron, rake, bundle, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to set up a cron job running a rake task. I'm using the gem Whenever. Here is the configuration in config/schedule.rb

```
every 1.minutes do
  bundle exec rake "test:pick_participant"
end
```

The crontab is set up correctly by Whenever:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/jsmith/webapp/releases/20111104200246 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake test:pick_participant --silent'
```

However, Cron keeps reporting (via mail) this error each time the job is ran:

```
From: root@SEQUOIA.local (Cron Daemon)
To: jsmith@SEQUOIA
Subject: Cron <jsmith@SEQUOIA> /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/jsmith/webapp/releases/20111104200246 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake test:pick_participant --silent'
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <MAILTO=jsmith@SEQUOIA>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/jsmith>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=jsmith>
Message-Id: <20111108002602.98F3E60227C@SEQUOIA.local>
Date: Mon,  7 Nov 2011 16:26:01 -0800 (PST)
expr: syntax error
Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources
```

The rake bundled in the application environment is version 0.8.7.

The command issued by Cron seems correct:

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/jsmith/webapp/releases/2067320376 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake test:pick_participant --silent'
```

it is calling `bundle exec rake` instead of `rake` directly.

Also if I issue the same command at the command line inside the application directory, the rake task runs successfully:

```
jsmith@SEQUOIA:~/webapp/current$ /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/jsmith/webapp/releases/20111104200246 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake test:pick_participant --silent'

* picked participant: Mindy!
```

Anyone has any ideas on why Cron is running into this error "couldn't find rake-0.8.7"?

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed the problem.

There were two problems, as reported in the Cron error output:

```
expr: syntax error
Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources
```

This is how I fixed them after some google search and debugging:

1. the `exp: syntax error` is specific to my Ubuntu 10.4 LTS installation. To fix it, in the file `/etc/profile.d/speechd-user-port.sh`, replace the line

   ```
   export SPEECHD_PORT=$(expr 6560 + $(getent passwd $USER | cut -f 3 -d :))
   ```

   with

   ```
   [ "$PS1" != "" ] && export SPEECHD_PORT=$(expr 6560 + $(getent passwd $USER | cut -f 3 -d :))
   ```

   The variable expansion $USER causes the syntax error. This is a bug in Ubuntu 10.4's speech-dispatcher package. See detailed explanations here:

   [Ubuntu bug#790173 Cron doesn't send output properly Comment 6](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/790173/comments/6)

   [Ubuntu bug#601114 /etc/profile.d/speechd-user-port.sh references $USER](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/speech-dispatcher/+bug/601114)
2. After the syntax error had been fixed, I continued getting the `Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources` error.

   This was due to RVM not loaded in my login session. This line that sources rvm function

   ```
   [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
   ```

   was only in ~/.bashrc, and **not** in ~/.bash_profile.

   The file ~/.bashrc is loaded for interactive non-login shell, and ~/.bash_profile is loaded for login shell, which is what is loaded by the `-l` switch in Cron job commmand "/bin/bash -l"

   This was my fault. The [RVM website](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) explicitly states putting the line in ~/.bash_profile.

   Adding the line to ~/.bash_profile, the Cron job successfully loads the RVM environment . Now, my Cron rake tasks work smoothly.

Here are a few things I learnt in debugging the issue:

- The Cron job environment is different from the command line of a login shell. The Cron environment is much more bare, and does not have many path/profile loaded like the login shell. That's why a command may work in the command line, but not as a Cron job.
- Cutting out Ruby on Rails and rake, I debugged Cron running the simplest commands, with crontab entries such as these:

  ```
  * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'pwd’
  * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $PATH’
  ```

  Or these in Whenever's config/schedule.rb

  ```
  every 1.minutes do
    rake "--version"
    command "rvm info"
  end
  ```

  These simple commands made me realize that the "expr: syntax error" was something fundamental unrelated to Cron or RoR, and the rake error was due to RVM not loaded correctly.
- there is a difference between [.bashrc and .bash_profile](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `/bin/bash -l -c` in crontab. This solved my issues with bundler, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just load your RVM environment with CRON and then you should be able to run whatever rake task, like so:

```
0 * * * * /home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm use ree-1.8.7-2011.03 rake name:task
```

Where `ree-1.8.7-2011.03` is the name of gemset to load, type `rvm list` to see your gemsets. Using a script file instead of a one-liner in your crontab makes it easier to manage, you could also use the command above in a script file, too.